# Excel - Best Way to Connect With Access Data

Tags: excel, ms-access, pivot-table

Here is the situation we have:

a) I have an Access database / application that records a significant amount of data. Significant fields would be hours, # of sales, # of unreturned calls, etc

b) I have an Excel document that connects to the Access database and pulls data in to visualize it

As it stands now, the Excel file has a Refresh button that loads new data. The data is loaded into a large PivotTable. The main 'visual form' then uses VLOOKUP to get the results from the form, based on the related hours.

This operation is slow (*~10 seconds*) and seems to be redundant and inefficient.
Is there a better way to do this?

I am willing to go just about any route - just need directions.

Thanks in advance!

**Update:** I have confirmed (due to helpful comments/responses) that the problem is with the data loading itself. removing all the VLOOKUPs only took a second or two out of the load time. So, the questions stands as how I can rapidly and reliably get the data without so much time involvement (it loads around **3000 records** into the PivotTables).

Comment: Any reason why you are working from the Excel end rather than the Access end?

Comment: The reporting is done in Excel so it can be sent to various team members and they can run the file and see the results from the remote database.

Comment: I mean why not use the Access end to put the data into Excel? It should be much quicker.

Comment: Is it possible/better to do this with various files? I think it would be ideal for us to be able to send a file to each person, rather than having them open the file remotely. It also needs to be refreshed on demand OR updated in real time (the latter being amazing, if possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find out if its the Pivot Table Refresh or the VLOOKUP thats taking the time.
(try removing the VLOOKUP to see how long it take just to do the Refresh).

If its the VLOOKUP you can usually speed that up.
(see http://www.decisionmodels.com/optspeede.htm for some hints)

If its the Pivot table Refresh then it depends on which method you are using to get the data (Microsoft Query, ADO/DAO, ...) and how much data you are transferring. 
One way to speed this up is to minimize the amount of data you are reading into the pivot cache by reducing the number of columns and/or predefining a query to subset the rows.

Comment: I am using the default Excel Data implementation. It was setup to just use an Access Query as an external data source - I haven't determined what connection method that is yet.

Comment: I removed all the VLOOKUPs. THe time is roughly the same - maybe a second or two's difference. I assume it is my data connection, which is accessing an external (and remote) data source - likely the issue. Just the same though, I assume there is a better connection method.

Comment: Ok, so check how long it takes to run the access query from your system.

Comment: It takes a few seconds. The query takes around 6 seconds to load in Access. Does this mean that Excel is running the query and THEN grabbing the data and bringing it in? (meaning it might be better to load raw data instead of a query) or am I way out to lunch?

Comment: OK, sounds like you need to look at exactly what method is being used to get the data into the pivot. probably you want to read the data from a query stored in the Access DB direct into the pivot.

Comment: Well yes, this is essentially what we are doing. The 'Data Source' chosen in the default External Data setup (Excel 2010) was the Access Database and that particular Query. We probably do 3 separate queries (Sales, Service, Month to Date). I know it's a fair amount of queries, so I wanted to see if there was a more efficient way of doing it. Is that what you are trying to get at? Is there a more direct way?

Comment: Unless you have calculated items or a lot of formulae(have you checked the effect of switching calculation to manual) the time to read a query directly into the pivot cache should be the same amount of time as running the query from your PC. But 6 secs does not equal 30 secs so there must be something else going on

Comment: I tried putting Calculations as 'Manual' - it went just as slow, if not even slower. I have no idea why it is so slow, but maybe it just needs to be rebuilt from scratch.

Comment: If there is commonality in the queries and pivots maybe you can design a single query that is read into a single pivot cache that feeds multiple pivots?